# Android ARCGIS loading data from REST API

Tags: android, rest, maps, arcgis

I am building an android application and I am using the ARCGIS android library.

I want to be able to load the data from:
http://tnmap.tn.gov/arcgis/rest/services/COMMUNITY/TN_GOV_PORTAL_LOCATIONS/FeatureServer

Into the app.

I can not seem to figure out how to use this REST api in combination with the ARCGIS android API. Any help would be appreciated.

I believe I must construct a url but for some reason I could not get anything working.

You can view the map using the arcgis viewer using the following URL:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftnmap.tn.gov%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FCOMMUNITY%2FTN_GOV_PORTAL_LOCATIONS%2FFeatureServer&source=sd

I have tried using that URL when building the map in Android and it does not seem to work.

Now I am thinking I have to use the Portal class somehow with combination of PortalItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the recent API changes I didn't realize that all I had to do is use a ServiceFeatureTable class.

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/data/ServiceFeatureTable.html